# Magento 2: REST API not returning data for orders using CRON?

Tags: magento2, api, cron, rest-api, crontab

I am getting order details using REST API. For this, I have written one controller in my custom module. When I am calling that controller from browser, it's is returning response but when I setup CRON for that then it is **not returning any response**.

Is there any special setting from **CRON** for **REST API**? Please help me how to get data of order using REST API from CRON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I got solution for this. I changed my code from **Controller** to **Model** and after that it's working fine. **Controller** is only for web so it was not working.